# I am getting Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of null when updating apexchart data dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux, properties, components, apexcharts

`let tableCellInfoList = []`
`let infoValueList = []`
`tableCellInfoList.push(<ChartContent data={infoValueList} field={field} />)`

`<Chart options={options} series={series} type="bar" height={300} width={'100%'}/>`
where series is comprised of props.data

but when infoValueList.length increases above 3, Chart becomes unstable and give Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of null

I am using the apexchart react library

Comment: but when I close the error window, and continue append data to the infoValueList, the Chart component will usually render chart correctly again, and I checked all the properties before and after adding data, they seem to be all there even when there's error

Comment: Inside the Chart component, I don't have any state, should I update format all the data with useState. right now I just format them before return

Comment: try this `series={series ? series : []}`

Comment: I tried this, doesn't work